# jQuery .html(): will it grab associated CSS information?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

On my page i have referenced an external css file like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/General.css">
```

this applies style to various HTML elements.

If i send all the HTML content to the server like so (to ultimately be made into a PDF):

```
    $.ajax({
    url: 'process.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        html: $("html").html()
    },
    success: function (data) {

    }
});
```

will the associated CSS be stored also? or will it not be since its not inline css?

If not, how can i overcome this so **all** website content gets sent to the server?

Comment: By "all website content" do you mean all external CSS, JS, and images, or only CSS and JS?

Comment: No it won't. HTML is HTML. CSS is CSS. If the element contains inline styles, you're right in that they will be sent as is, but they're only meaningful if the consuming application actually understands inline styles - otherwise, they're just "part of the markup".

Comment: JS files are not necessary as i only want to create a PDF file but i dont mind anyway if the solution is quick and easy for all content. The idea is i want the pdf to be exactly like the html page visually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some jQuery code that takes external CSS and inlines it, which may be helpful:

```
$("link").each(function(i, el) {
    var jel = $(el);
    var href = jel.attr("href");
    if(href && jel.attr("rel") === "stylesheet") {
        $.when($.get(href))
        .done(function(response) {
            $('<style />').text(response).appendTo($('head'));
            jel.remove();
        });
    }
});
```

This code will go through the stylesheet links in your document head and inline each of them. This will capture all the CSS as long as the CSS files don't have any external dependencies, such as images, fonts, or imports.

Please keep in mind that it's asynchronous, so if you want to know when it's done, you will need to give it a callback when all the assets are retrieved.